# issue with java script functions

Tags: javascript

I am adding two text boxes using function and want to display result in third text box. For this I used two functions. First `getdata()` to read first textbox value and second is `getdata1()` to read second textbox value. I also use onchange event. but in result it display `NaN`. Please, help me.
Here is my Code

```js
var a, b, c;

function getdata(txt) {
  x = txt.value;
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    a = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt").value);
  } else {
    alert("Input not valid");
    txt.focus();
    txt.value = "";
  }
}

function getdata1(txt) {
  x = txt.value;
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    b = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt").value);
  } else {
    alert("Input not valid");
    txt.focus();
    txt.value = "";
  }
}

function myFunction(s, t) {
  var s = a;
  var t = b;
  var c = s + t;
  document.getElementById("result").value = c;
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" name="txt[]" id="txt[]" onchange="getdata(this)" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txt[]" id="txt[]" onchange="getdata1(this)" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="result" id="result" onfocus="myFunction()" /></td>
```

Comment: write question and code in proper format and provide your html code

Comment: you have given both text boxes with same `id` which is one of the reason for the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Read this!! and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use same `id` values for different element! Use `x` values instead of `document.getElementById("txt").value`.

```js
var a, b, c;
function TryParceData(src, old) {
  x = src.value;
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    return parseInt(x);
  } else {
    alert("Input not valid");
    src.focus();
    src.value = "";
    return old;
  }
}
function getdata(txt) {
  a = TryParceData(txt, a);
  myFunction();
}

function getdata1(txt) {
  b = TryParceData(txt, b);
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction(s, t) {
  var s = a;
  var t = b;
  var c = s + t;
  document.getElementById("result").value = c;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txt[]" onchange="getdata(this)" />
<input type="text" name="txt[]" onchange="getdata1(this)" />
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" onfocus="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: Thankx for this lovely solution. problem is solved but one more thing is that when onchange event occur in text2 then result show. means reflection should be done from both text boxes. plz help for this also.

Comment: @VishalGoyal, l did not understatnd. Do you want to show result in `#result` input when first or second input is changed?

Comment: @VishalGoyal, append `myFunction();` line into both `getdata()` and `getdata1()` functions. I have made corresponding changes of my code.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you have multiple element that has the same ids, the first or last will be the only one fetched by your selector. Second, attribute 'id' is called id because it gives identity to your element, which basically means try not to give same identity to each elements. Third, you're getting NaN because you're looking for an element with id 'txt' but there is none in your page (this error occurs in your parseInt part). The id of your element is 'txt[]'. Try changing those ids to 'txt1' and 'txt2' for the other one and change your scripts. Update me when you've fixed it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var a, b, c;

function getdata(txt) {
  x = parseInt(txt.value);
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    a = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt").value);
  } else {
    txt.focus();
    txt.value = "";
  }
}

function getdata1(txt) {
  x = parseInt(txt.value);
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    b = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
  } else {
    txt.focus();
    txt.value = "";
  }
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  var c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").value = c;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onblur="getdata(this)">
<input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="getdata1(this)">
<input type="text" id="result">
```