# issue with java script functions to add text boxes

Tags: javascript

I want to add two text boxes and display result in third text box. and same for next remaining rows. here is my code

**java script**

```
var a,b,c;
function getdata(txt)
{
x=txt.value;

    if (!isNaN(x)) 
        {

        a=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);

        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Input not valid");
            txt.focus();
            txt.value="";
        }

      }
      function getdata1(txt)
      {
        x=txt.value;
        if (!isNaN(x)) 
        {

        b=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Input not valid");
            txt.focus();
            txt.value="";
        }
        myFunction();
      }
    function myFunction(s,t) 
    {
        var s=a;
        var t=b;
        var c=s+t;
        document.getElementById("result").value= c;         
    }
```

Please refer the below image.
[image][1]

**html code**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue with java script functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644185/issue-with-java-script-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed parameter for **myFunction** method while calling. Also did invalid parameter declaration in **myFunction** method. Please try below code.

```
var a,b,c; 
function getdata(txt)
{ 
   x=txt.value;
   if (!isNaN(x)) 
    {

    a=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);

    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Input not valid");
        txt.focus();
        txt.value="";
    }

  }
  function getdata1(txt)
  {
    x=txt.value;
    if (!isNaN(x)) 
    {

    b=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Input not valid");
        txt.focus();
        txt.value="";
    }
    myFunction(a,b);
  }
  function myFunction(a,b) 
  {
      var s=a;
      var t=b;
      var c=s+t;
      document.getElementById("result").value=c;
  }
```